# R swirl() course Getting and Cleaning data Manipulating Data with dplyr. R runs into fatal error

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, swirl

dplyr package loads correctly but then this error appears:

> Error in (function (srcref)  : unimplemented type (29) in 'eval'
> In addition: Warning message:
> `tbl_df()` is deprecated as of dplyr 1.0.0.
> Please use `tibble::as_tibble()` instead.
> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
> Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
> ...

[image]

R version 4.0.2

Rstudio 1.2.5033

swirl 2.4.5

dplyr 1.0.2

Windows 10

Comment: What versions of RStudio, swirl and dplyr do you have?

Comment: @Phil Rstudio 4.0.2, swirl 2.4.5, dplyr 1.0.2

Comment: You're confusing R and Rstudio. The latest version of Rstudio is 1.3.

Comment: @Phil Sorry. It's 1.2.5033

Comment: Update Rstudio to the latest version and see if the crash still happens.